# Spring custom filter is not working with service layer method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, filter, servlet-filters

I found the solution, but I do not understand why this works, but the other one does not..

the issue is, when I cast ServletRequest to HttpServletReuqest and pass the request to one of the Service method, it just stops there. it is trying to throw the error and I am not sure.

the service method is working fine when I use it in the controller..(the issue was fixed when I copied the identical code to the filter class.. but I do not understand why it breaks, when I am using it in the service, but it works when I have it in my servlet filter class)

here is my code:

```
public class AdminFilter extends GenericFilterBean { 

private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("alog");
@Autowired
AccessService accessService;

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

    if(request == null) {
        LOGGER.trace("request is null... why?"); //it was not null
    }
    if(httpRequest == null) {
        LOGGER.trace("httpRequest(after the cast) is null... why?");//it was not null
    }
    try {
        if (accessService.isAdmin(httpRequest)) {
            LOGGER.trace("User is Admin");
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception E) {
        LOGGER.error("Request is empty : " + E.getStackTrace());//stack trace just gets null exception for not having a sepcific error handling 
    }

}
```

and here is my service layer method:

```
    public boolean isAdmin(HttpServletRequest request) {
        LOGGER.trace("checking if the user is admin"); //this is never triggered.
        String user = request.getRemoteUser();

        //some logic here
        if (//some logic here) {
            //some logic here
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;   
        }
    }
```

so the code breaks when it hits the "isAdmin(request)"

But it works fine if i do not use the service method that's autowired..

it works if I just copy and paste the exact code into my AdminFilter class and use the code like

```
if (isAdmin(httpRequest)) 


//instead of   
if (accessService.isAdmin(httpRequest))
```

I know I have the solution.. But i really want to understand why...

Comment: Let me guess, the service isn't auto wired but is null.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the right impl of your service autowird? debug and see if the service is null or another impl?

Comment: Hello. I know this is a abit old post, but wanted to share what I found. I confirmed that the @Autowired stuff were NULL...  I am just a bit baffled as it was working on my local but when i tried it on the remote it was not. The research shows that I can't use autowire with servlet filters as servlet filter is wired with web.xml.